# Classes. Is it possible to avoid writing a constructor, when there are props?

Tags: typescript, class

For example I have a class and an interface for props:

```
interface PropsInterface {
 propertyName: dataType
}
```

```
class Example {
  constructor(props: PropsInterface) {
     this.exampleProps = props
  }

  exampleProps: PropsInterface
}
```

Is it possible to avoid writing a constructor ?

For example something similar to React class components with props, where we can simply write so:

```
class Example extends React.Component<PropsInterface, any> {
  exampleProps = this.props.propertyName
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can qualify constructor parameters with an access modifier (`private`, `protected`, `public` or `readonly`), and they will automatically get converted into class properties:

```
interface PropsInterface {
  propertyName: string;
}

class Example {
  constructor(public props: PropsInterface) {}
}

console.log(new Example({ propertyName: 'test' }).props);
```

The handbook refers to this as "parameter properties". See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) for details.

Answer (score -2):

If you put a ! at the end of propertyName, typescript won't check if it's in the constructor.

```
 interface PropsInterface {
     propertyName!: dataType
 }
```

Comment: That won't even compile.

Comment: Interesting, what does it say?